# Пошаговая форма

Tags: javascript

Как создавать пошаговые формы регистрации? Поделитесь ссылками.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примеры.

- [Преобразование длинной формы в пошаговый мастер регистрации](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=622)
- [Превратите любую веб-форму в яркий пошаговый мастер с помощью jQuery](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=432)
- [Building a jQuery Step-by-Step Form](http://brenelz.com/blog/building-a-jquery-step-by-step-form/)

В сети таких примеров много. Искать по словам: jquery пошаговая форма регистрации.

Answer (score 3):

- [JQuery AJAX PayPal Cart Form Plugin](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1078/JQuery-AJAX-PayPal-Cart-Form-Plugin)
- [Jquery tab menu Wizard Plugin](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/739/Jquery-tab-menu-Wizard-Plugin)

Простенько и со вкусом. )