# Форма с несколькими этапами заполнения

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать на сайте форму, которую пользователь будет заполнять в несколько шагов. Например, после загрузки страницы у пользователя просят ввести его пол и возраст, после заполнения, пользователь нажимает кнопку отправки формы, и на странице появляются новые поля формы для заполнения.. и т.д.

Можно создать блоки с нужными полями формы, скрывать их в ненужный момент и показывать в нужный. Но есть ли более "изящное решение" или формы такого типа именно так и реализовывается?

Comment: Какой сервер/back-end?

Comment: в смысле? не понял

Comment: На веб-сервере какой код - ASP.NET, php, RoR? Или это сайт из html страниц? Куда форма отправляется?

Comment: аааа... php-обработчик

Comment: Ну вариантов-то - два. Полностью на клиенте - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80082/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0?rq=1, или с submit'ами на сервер между шагами - особенно если проверка данных каждого шага требует сложной серверной логики.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас это первый опыт написания такой формы, тогда не усложняйте. Наиболее простое решение - это разбить заполнение формы на шаги, которые определяются переменной `$step = 1,2,3...` и на каждом шаге прописать те данные вашей формы, которые должны отображаться для пользователя. Дополнительно подключите сессию PHP для хранения введенных пользователем данных.

Именно так реализуется такая форма : [image: Пошаговое заполнение формы]
Решение можно сделать "более изящным" если подключить AJAX, т.е. обработку формы без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делается именно так как сказали вы (части формы скрываются и показываются).

Отправлять промежуточные данные на сервер и обновлять всю страницу (проверенные данные складывать скажем в сессию) тоже можно, но нужно только в особом случае, т.к. при этом клиент будет видеть мерцания и ждать загрузки формы.

В добавок нельзя будет вернуть клиента на тот же шаг при смене сессии (это для обоих случаев верно).

Comment: Зато такой вариант хорош, если ориентируемся на пользователей без js (хотя это уже редкость)

Comment: @Zelta согласен.
В этом случае можно данные в hidden поля пихать на новом шаге вместо хранения на сервере.