# Калькулятор кухонь

Tags: html, css

Есть калькулятор кухонь, при выборе определенных данных расчитывается стоимость заказа. Отображается только 1-ый шаг, всем остальным задан display:none; . Разметка примерно такая:

```
<div class="calculation">
    <div class="step1"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step2"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step3"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step4"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step5"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step6"><input type="submit"></div>
    <div class="step7"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку калькулятор просто переходил к следующему шагу без какого-либо расчета стоимости и без перезагрузки страницы, т.е. чтобы предыдущий блок принимал значение display:none; , а следующий display:block;.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/80082/176064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Разметка *примерно* такая:

Тогда ответ *примерно* такой: в моей практике был задействован плагин для jQuery который называется [dm-tabs.js](https://pastebin.com/raw/Tx2UTjmZ)

Однако я бы не стал его подключать. Подобная задача решается тривиально на коленке за 15-60 минут хоть на чистом javascript. Ссылка как пример от чего отталкиваться.

---

PS: Насколько могу судить, это техническое сообщество. Здесь не интересует такое понятие как "калькулятор" "кухонь" когда суть вопроса - как последовательно поменять display на множестве блоков HTML. Поэтому был -1 (не от меня)